# Is this transform being positioned properly?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am trying to create a new Transform with the same position as my already existing RectTransform through code.

```
        if (item.rowIndex != -1 && item.columnIndex == 0) {
            Debug.Log(item.transform.localPosition);
            GameObject transformGO = new GameObject("Transform #" + (transformsCount + 1));
            transformGO.transform.SetParent(transform, true);
            transformGO.transform.localPosition = new Vector2(item.rectTransform.localPosition.x, item.rectTransform.localPosition.y);
            possiblePositions[transformsCount] = transformGO.transform;
            transformsCount++;
        }
```

The visual I see on the editor does not match what I thought was going to happen (I want the transform to be centered in the middle of the object). Is this just a visual bug or is the newly created transform not actually at the correct position?

[RectTransform position](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rFcOr.png)

[Transform position](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kXl5V.png)

Answer (score 0):

I was not setting the parent correctly. It is working fine now.

Comment: What specifically was the problem? What code did you change to resolve it? Remember, answers are meant to aid future readers with a similar issue. As is, this doesn’t give enough information to do that.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).